# Why source maps does not work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, haxe, flashdevelop, source-maps

I have chrome 39.0.2171.71, and I have enable source mapping check box enabled, but hx files are empty in debugger, any one can help explain why source mapping does not work?

**EDIT**

I am not using a server, I am opening the HTML file directly in chrome
In chrome network tab, I can see:

```
(failed)
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND


file:///C:/Users/samir.s.MOTAHIDAEDU/Documents/haxe/quiz-generator/bin/file:/C:/Users/samir.s.MOTAHIDAEDU/Documents/haxe/quiz-generator/src/com/quiz/Question.hx
```

I compile the js project, like this:

```
haxe  -debug --each -lib createjs -lib Actuate -cp src -js C:/Users/samir.s.MOTAHIDAEDU/Documents/haxe/quiz-generator/bin/Quizgenerator.js -main Main -resource quiz.txt@quiz_text_file -lib random
```

**EDIT 2**

Where can I set the source map of my project? I think I just have to set the path correctly, I am on Windows 7

Comment: We need more info. How are you compiling the files? How are you serving the files? Does the network inspector say that it is successfully fetching the files? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Please check EDIT above

Comment: It seems that I have to fix the path of hx files, why is that "file:/C:/Users/samir.s.MOTAHIDAEDU/Documents/haxe/quiz-generator/src/" added after "/bin/" folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a Google Chrome bug, since it cannot load the local files.

You could try to compile with the compiler flag `-D source-map-content`. This include the hx sources as part of the JS source map. For me this works pretty good.

Comment: It is confirmed by Google as being a "feature": https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=446060